# aircraftLocation() returns zeroes

Tags: dji-sdk

Im having trouble making this work. Yes, im a newbee programer so this might just be a really really dumb question.

```
DJIFlightControllerCurrentState dronePosition = new DJIFlightControllerCurrentState();

public double getLong (){
    double Long = dronePosition.getAircraftLocation().getLongitude();
    return Long;
}

public double getLat (){
    double Lat = dronePosition.getAircraftLocation().getLatitude();
    return Lat;
}
```

When trying this out with my Phantom 3 PRO all i get back are zeroes's. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all 0 values because you are newing the object.  What you should do it to ask the aircraft for the current state like this:

Application.getAircraftInstance().getFlightController().getCurrentState();

The return is an instance of DJIFlightControllerCurrentState, which contains, amongst other things, the aircraft's location informaiton